# accordion not working in function

Tags: javascript, accordion

I am working with the accordion menu in javascript, here is the code

```
    <body> 
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
<div style="width:50%;float: left;height:50%;" id="accordion"></div>

<script>

var html = '';
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..';
// first we generating our html in the loop
for(var i=0 ; i<6 ; i++) {
  html += '<h3>Section ' + i + '</h3>' + '<div><p>' + text + '</p></div>';
}
document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = html;

// next we're inserting html into block with ID accordion

</script>
```

it works fine, but when i put it in a function, it doen't work
This code doesn't work

```
    <body onload="test()"> 
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
<div style="width:50%;float: left;height:50%;" id="accordion"></div>

<script>
function test(){
var html = '';
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..';
// first we generating our html in the loop
for(var i=0 ; i<6 ; i++) {
  html += '<h3>Section ' + i + '</h3>' + '<div><p>' + text + '</p></div>';
}
document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = html;
}
</script>
```

How can i make the accordion menu work within functions??

Comment: Isn't it invoked from this line: onload="test()"?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it doesnt work when it's inside a function is because you are not calling the function explicitly.
Define the function at a convenient place and then call it from the documentOnLoad function so that the script gets all the referred elements when it executes.

EDIT:cant believe i missed the  `onload="test()"` line.
which makes me think the reason might be the execution order. you are calling test before defining it, which can be a reason. define the test function somewhere in top portion (before `onload=test()`) that might do the trick.
Also calling the test from the $(function()...) might be a good idea because that will definately execute after `documentReady` and before calling the `.accordion()` function
P.S. take this as a suggestion rather than a concrete answer as am unable to test my answer myself bcz am in my workplace.

Comment: Isn't it called from this line: onload="test()"?

Comment: What do you mean by convenient place?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the function in between the script tags aswell. You didn't close your script tag.

Comment: The script tag is closed, but i forgot to paste it.
Post edited

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, here is the correct code:

```
    <head>
  <script>
function test(){
var html = '';
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..';
for(var j=0 ; j<6 ; j++){
for(var i=0 ; i<1 ; i++) {
  html += '<h3>Section ' + j + '</h3>' + '<div><p>' + text + '</p></div>';
}
document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = html;
}

    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
}
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="test()"> 
<div style="width:50%;float: left;height:50%;" id="accordion"></div>
</body>
```